# A shear in y from a combination of rotations and shear in x

Tags: graphics, transformation

I'm trying to complete a shear in y as a composite of shears in x and rotations.

I've tried multiple ways on paper, and the closest I got was a
shear - rotation - sheer.

Mathematically, it always seems to get to a point where we have conflicting equations;

e.g

sin(theta) = m

or

cos(theta) = 1

cos(theta) + n sin(theta) = 1

Comment: What about rotate, shear, rotate?

Comment: I haven't tried this combo. I guess it just felt the combination didnt really make sense, but now i think about it, it might work